# Check if string end with substring, Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl, match

I have a searching string `.state_s[0]` and another two lists of strings:

```
{cache.state_s[0]} {cache.state_s[1]}
```

and

```
{cache.state_s[0]a} {cache.state_s[1]}
```

I need command(s) Tcl interpreter accepts to ask if the searching string is matching any of the items in the string list. What is also very important, the solution should only return positive result for the first list. I tried:

```
set pattern {.state_s[0]}
set escaped_pattern [string map {* \\* ? \\? [ \\[ ] \\] \\ \\\\} $pattern]
set m1 {{cache.state_s[0]} {cache.state_s[1]}}
set m2 {{cache.state_s[0]a} {cache.state_s[1]}}
regexp $escaped_pattern $m1
regexp $escaped_pattern $m2
```

However, the above commands are returning "1" with both regexp calls.

Basically, I need a way to check if a substring (having special chars like [) is at the end of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the elements as a list in a variable `m1`.

```
set m1 {{cache.state_s[0]} {cache.state_s[1]}}
set m2 {{cache.state_s[0]a} {cache.state_s[1]}}
```

But, when you apply it against `regexp`, Tcl will treat the input `m1` as a whole string, not a list.

Since both the list contains the string `.state_s[0]`, `regexp` returning the result as 1.

If you want to apply the regular expression for each element, then I would recommend to use the `lsearch` with `-regexp` flag.

```
% set m1 {{cache.state_s[0]} {cache.state_s[1]}}
{cache.state_s[0]} {cache.state_s[1]}
% set m2 {{cache.state_s[0]a} {cache.state_s[1]}}
{cache.state_s[0]a} {cache.state_s[1]}
%
% lsearch -regexp -inline $m1 {\.state_s\[0]$};
cache.state_s[0]
% lsearch -regexp -inline $m2 {\.state_s\[0]$}
%
```

The pattern I have used here is `{\.state_s\[0]$}`. The last `$` symbol represents end of line. With this, we are ensuring that the element doesn't have any more characters in it. We don't have escape the closing square bracket `]` in Tcl.